# audio on timeline with custom open graph action

Tags: facebook-graph-api, audio, facebook-ios-sdk

I have an iPhone app which posts a custom action (via facebook-ios-sdk 3.1) on a custom object. There is a webpage for the custom object which has og tags. So when this action is posted, it shows up on user's timeline with information from the og tags from the custom object's page. Good, but what I can't make work is getting an audio player to show up on the timeline post. On the custom object page there is og:audio tags. I have read that if users like a page with og:audio tags, it will put an audio player on the timeline post. Can this work also for custom open graph actions? Right now the tag appears to be just ignored and no audio data is visible on the timeline post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be a whitelisted developer for Open Graph Music, according to this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/music/
My guess is you would also need to be implementing the "Listen" built-in action, instead of a custom action.

As an alternative, you might be able to associate your object with a video, and host your page's audio files as a video with static album art or something (documentation for video properties here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-objects/#video)

I know that's a bit of a hack but it may work for you.